# Clearing Cell values and keeping formulas for all next rows based on a change in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a VBA code that clears all next rows values but keeps the formulas, based on a change on any cell in D column

for example:

if i changed D3, I want the range A4:J100 to clear only the values but keep formulas, and if i changed D4 the the range will be A5:j100

I've found some codes that fill ,y requirement partially, but I couldn't combine them together.

this code for clearing values but keeping formulas

```
Sub RemoveConstants()

    Dim rConstants As Range

    Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rConstants.ClearContents

End Sub
```

and this code for deleting cells based on deleting a cell on the same row (and delete the formulas)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("M" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'do nothing if multiple cells changed

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent an endless loop of this code
    Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":J100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well you can do `Range("D:D").clearcontents`. The code above will clear constants from D anyway.